# Showing Measure Value only the First Date & Last Date of the Date Slicer Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, dashboard, powerbi-desktop, ssas-tabular

I am working on a Power BI Report (which is in direct query mode with `SSAS tabular model` as source). I need to create two measures  **`opening base`** and **`closing base`** with below condition.

**opening base should be show value only for the minimum date range chosen by the user in the date slicer.**

**closing base should be show value only for the maximum date range chosen by the user in the date slicer.**

For e.g : if user chooses between **may 1, 2020** and **may 17,2020** **`opening base`** will show value only for may 1, 2020  & **`closing base`** show value only for may 17th,2020. For other dates value should be **0**.   I have tried below

Created a measure to get the minimum date of the date slicer.

```
StartDate = CALCULATE(min('DATE'[DATE]),ALLSELECTED('DATE'[DATE]))
```

used this measure as filter in the opening base measure calculation.

```
openingbase = CALCULATE(sum(MEASUREMENTS[OPENING_BASE]),FILTER('DATE','DATE'[DATE]=[StartDate]))
```

But this is not working as I am getting opening base value for all the date ranges selected. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: can you try FILTER(RELATED('DATE') etc rather than FILTER('DATE'